# react willReceiveProps workaround for external library

Tags: reactjs, render, web-component

I'm using a react datepicker component that can be found [here](http://zippyui.com/docs/react-date-picker). The component is pretty great except for what appears to be an oversight: it does not implement `willReceiveProps`.

To expound, I create the datpicker as below:

```
<DateField
  dateFormat= { dateFormat}
  forceValidDate={true}
  defaultValue={startDate || ''}
  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(null, 'start_date')}
  id="start"
>
  <DatePicker
    navigation={true}
    locale="en"
    forceValidDate={true}
    highlightWeekends={true}
    highlightToday={true}
    weekNumbers={true}
    weekStartDay={0}
  />
</DateField>
```

Note above that there is a prop `defaultValue` which I pass `startDate`. Now, `startDate` can and does change for reasons that are sometimes external to the component. That value is passed during a new `render()` action as per usual. According to react philosophy this shouldn't be a problem.

However, it appears to me as if the value from `defaultValue` is only ever read once inside `DateField`. It is read as `this.props.defaultValue`. Anyone who has ever built a component relying on props should quickly recognize this is a problem. It means that when the prop is changed the new value will not be used.

Because this is a library, I cannot simply implement `willReceiveProps`. Does anyone know of a good workaround to get this component to either completely reset on a `render` or some other strategy to deal with what seems to be a big design problem?

Comment: I suppose that if you will add `key={startDate}` to your `DateField` - it will be re-rendered when startDate will change.

Comment: Are you double sure they have not implemented `willReceiveProps`? Because its not always necessary to implement it as react updates the component itself. Did u use `shouldComponentUpdate()` in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They follow the same standards as the `<input>` component. `defaultValue` is read only once but there is also `value` that can be set externally. There is no need for them to use `willReceiveProps`.

In short, use `value` instead of `defaultValue`.

See [Uncontrolled Components in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

PS: I am looking a bit into the code and it seems there are also properties `text` and `date` apart from `value`. Since the code (and documentation) has been removed from github, I won't inspect what is the difference between those props.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining in detail. I'm pretty new to react, and did not know that this standard existed. `value` worked fine.